# Can you filter out personal details from Python Twilio logger?

Tags: twilio, python-logging, twilio-python

By default the Twilio Python client seems to log out personal information (emails and numbers). I know you can access the logger like this `twilio_logger = logging.getLogger('twilio.http_client')`

Is there a simple setting change we can make to filter out this personal information, either directly through the library or by changing the logger?

NOTE: I have attempted to do this by creating a custom formatter:

```
class SensitiveDataFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    """Formatter that removes sensitive information in urls."""
    @staticmethod
    def _filter(s):
        print('filter')
        return re.sub(r'([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,})', r'[email_redacted]', s)

    def format(self, record):
        original = logging.Formatter.format(self, record)
        return self._filter(original)


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'sensitive'
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO'
    },
    'formatters': {
        'sensitive': {
            '()': 'my_project.settings.logging.sensitive_data_formatter.SensitiveDataFormatter'
        }
    }
}
```

This works in the general case, however I'm struggling to apply it to Twilio

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can [apply filters to Python loggers using logger config and a custom class that inherits from `logging.Filter`](https://relaxdiego.com/2014/07/logging-in-python.html#redacting-logs-using-a-custom-formatter).

I'm not a Python developer, so pointing you to [this blog post](https://relaxdiego.com/2014/07/logging-in-python.html) is the best way I can answer this question. I will note that the post appears to be from 2014, so may need updates for Python 3, but the [Python logging documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) is also pretty extensive, so should help you out here.

Comment: Thanks @philnash. I actually tried this approach, but couldn't seem to get it to apply to the twilio logger, so was hoping there was an official example/method somewhere

Comment: What did you do to try to apply this? Can you update your question with the logger filters and the log config that you tried?

Comment: Sorry - very slow here @philnash. I've added above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can configure the Twilio logger in the Python library to use a custom formatter. To test this I took your formatter and modified it to redact Twilio accounts, messaging services and phone numbers.

```py
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

class SensitiveDataFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    @staticmethod
    def _filter(s):
        filters = [
            [r'(AC[a-f0-9]+)', '[account_redacted]'],
            [r'(MG[a-f0-9]+)', '[messaging_service_redacted]'],
            [r'(\+[0-9]+)', '[phone_redacted]'],
        ]
        for f in filters:
            s = re.sub(f[0], f[1], s)
        return s

    def format(self, record):
        original = logging.Formatter.format(self, record)
        return self._filter(original)

# create a logging handler with the custom formatter attached
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(SensitiveDataFormatter())

# add the stream handler to the Twilio logger
client.http_client.logger.addHandler(handler)
client.http_client.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Example log after sending an SMS:

```
POST Request: https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[account_redacted]/Messages.json
PAYLOAD: {'To': '[phone_redacted]', 'From': '[messaging_service_redacted]', 'Body': 'Friendly reminder that you have an appointment with us next week.'}
POST Response: 201 {"sid": "SM4428eb430949461d9bd58d44da1dd999", "date_created": "Thu, 19 May 2022 08:57:49 [phone_redacted]", "date_updated": "Thu, 19 May 2022 08:57:49 [phone_redacted]", "date_sent": null, "account_sid": "[account_redacted]", "to": "[phone_redacted]", "from": null, "messaging_service_sid": "[messaging_service_redacted]", "body": "Friendly reminder that you have an appointment with us next week.", "status": "accepted", "num_segments": "0", "num_media": "0", "direction": "outbound-api", "api_version": "2010-04-01", "price": null, "price_unit": null, "error_code": null, "error_message": null, "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/[account_redacted]/Messages/SM4428eb430949461d9bd58d44da1dd999.json", "subresource_uris": {"media": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/[account_redacted]/Messages/SM4428eb430949461d9bd58d44da1dd999/Media.json"}}
```